# Ajax : add/remove div using chekboxes

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm creating a web page for my internship and I want to add a div "example" when the checkbox named "example" is checked. I want to delete this div when it's unchecked.
I really don't know how to start, and what to do.

Edit :
Ok I see.
I have several checkboxes, is there a way to do it for everyone ?

Here I create my checkboxes :

```
my %labels = (
        'rdc7' => 'switch-rdc-7',
        'rdc8' => 'switch-rdc-8',
        'rdc4' => 'switch-rdc-4',
        '3750' => 'switch-3750' 
      );

    print $cgi->checkbox_group(
        -name => 'switch_choices',
        -values => ['rdc4', 'rdc7', 'rdc8', '3750'],
        -default => ['rdc7', 'rdc8'],
        -labels => \%labels
    );
```

And when it's checked, I want to add a div by :
`my $switch1 = SwitchGUI->new("switch-rdc-7", 24, 2);`
(it produce a div with id="switch-rdc-7").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<script>
    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            $(this).after( $('<div class="example_text">Example</div>') );
        }else{
            $(this).next('.example_text').remove();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There's no need to introduce a dependency on JQuery simply to show/hide a div.

Comment: jQuery is an extremely common package. And he didn't say that it was required to accomplish it without a industry standard javascript library. There's a reason people write libraries.

Comment: Maybe not, but the chances are that won't be the only javascript on the page, plus serving from the Google CDN means the script is likely to already be cached by potential users

Comment: Little problem, .after() adds near the checkbox, how to add in the body or in a specific div ?

Comment: You need to select it...  like:  $('#specific_div_id').append( $('<div>Example</div>') );  See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Ok I found how to do. Is it possible to add perl/CGI instead of pure html ? I mean I don't want to append $('<div>Example</div>') but SwitchGUI->new("switch-rdc-7", 24, 2) which produce a representation of my switch.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an onClick() event for the Checkbox and then determine if the Checkbox is selected or not. Depending on the settings, you could show/hide content of that div.

You would need to use AJAX if you are going to fetch it from the server.